# How to hide Popover when the binder gets unbinded in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

So I started making a little game using KnockoutJS.
I found this nice binding handler to use with popovers: https://github.com/s-stude/knockout-popover.

The issue is that when 'initialConstructionGoing' turns to false and the content disappear, the popover is frozen. I tried making a setTimeout to make it go away but it didn't work.

```
<!-- ko if: initialConstructionGoing -->
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle icon-gradient-warning" class="ko-popover" data-bind="popover: true, popoverOptions: { title: 'Under construction' }" ></i>
<!-- /ko -->
```

What would be a good approach to this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it work to change "popover: true" to data-bind="popover: initialConstructionGoing"? I'm uncertain whether the "popover" binding or the "if" binding would get evaluated first.

Comment: I tried, the popover is still displayed, but once 'initialConstructionGoing' it set to false and the content disappear, the popover is frozen and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: It seems like it's just an order of operations problem. If you can find a way to set the popover binding to false before the initialConstructionGoing gets set to false it should have time to clean up before the element is removed from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Jason, Id didn't think of that. I'll modify my code and post it here once it's working.